# How do I get an excellent attack with a shell?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

I've never managed to get higher than a "nice" attack using a shell... in fact that's the only attack rating I *ever* get. What's the trick to getting an excellent attack with a shell?

Comment: Pretty much any time Mario is about to land on something, you want to press the button for an extra attack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get an excellent rating with a shell you need to press A **both times** Mario jumps on the shell. The first time being when the koopa is walking into the battle, and the second jump being the one which launches the shell. If you only perform **one** of these jumps you'll get a nice rating.

Comment: Yeah this answer makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

With a shell, it starts to fold - this is where you get the Nice rating. When it is till folded, right before it launches, hit A again, and you should get an Excellent rating.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what you are trying to say. After I figured it out on my own I can see what you were trying to say, but I still feel as if it's a confusing description. I've added my own answer with what I believe to be a more clear description for future users.